# SQLAlchemy + postgres: hangs when fetching all rows of empty table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres database. I use SQLAlchemy to interact with it. I have a script that reads/writes stuff in the database.

Many operations in this script work well. Rows are inserted in the DB. The setup seems operational. But:

At some point in the script I'm trying to read from an empty table (I know it's empty, but I need to try anyway in case it's not):

```
logger.debug("Fetching pizza entries...")
all_entries = session.query(Pizzas).all()
logger.debug("All pizzas fetched")
```

And this particular query hangs (15 minutes, but it eventually completes). I don't understand why. When I use a sqlite database, this runs as expected (i.e: I get an empty list immediately).

Can you guys advise please?

EDIT: somewhere else in the script I run this code again, but this time the table contains rows. In this case the query behaves as expected, i.e it returns in around a minute.

EDIT2: the postgres server is running locally.

Comment: Could there be a problem in the network? Or try looking at raw SQL, which generates by `Query` instance.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the postgres server is local. Question amended. I'll look at the raw SQL.